# is it possible for a router to provide different gateway?

Tags: router, gateway

i have tp-link wireless router 192.168.10.188, i was can make it function as DHCP provider(range 192.168.10.100 to 192.168.10.109). the only thing that i cannot make it work as intended, is for it to provide different gateway (192.168.10.1), the computers that obtain IP from that router properly get everything(dynamic IP and dns IP), but there is no function on that router to provide different gateway, the computers always get the router's address(192.168.10.188) as gateway.

is there a router that can provide different gateway other than its own address?

or the question should be, is the dhcp of a router can provide different gateway other than its own address?

note: i cannot make the wireless router address as 192.168.10.1, we have main router(non-wireless, address is 192.168.10.1) that is connected directly to internet

Answer (score 2):

Generally, a DHCP server is able to provide any IP you like as the default router. Only the GUI used for configuration is often stripped down to a minimal set of features, so you just can not alter the DHCP option.

You could check if your main router can serve DHCP, too or move the DHCP service to another server on your network. If you have any Linux servers, install ISC's `dhcpd`. The DHCP service for Windows Server is also free of extra charge.

The ultimate solution would be slightly different: Create another IP subnet for the wifi and let the AP route beween wifi and wired network (*routing* instead of *bridging*). Then, on the wireless-router, use your main router's IP as default gateway.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a router that can provide
>   different gateway other than its own
>   address?
>   or the question should be, is the dhcp
>   of a router can provide different
>   gateway other than its own address?

That is manufacture dependent. My Linksys WRT54GL allows any setting.